# Tiny URL redirection works in browser, but from curl returns 200 instead of 301

Tags: curl, tinyurl

This looks weird to me, may be I'm missing something obvious. Following is a sample tinyurl:

http://tinyurl.com/67lwfe

it works for my browser, redirects properly to the desired page. But when I try using curl like the following:

```
curl -I http://tinyurl.com/67lwfe
```

It responds with 200 instead of a 3xx response. I thought the page might be responding with a meta refresh html tag, so I tried:

```
curl http://tinyurl.com/67lwfe
```

But it responds blank with no html or meta refresh tags. So my question is how the browser knows to redirect properly? I've also tried setting browser agents with no luck. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I get a 301 doing `curl -I http://tinyurl.com/67lwfe`. Are you behind a really bad proxy?

Comment: @minitech interesting! I'm getting 200 from both my home and linode server network. Being behind a bad proxy shouldn't enable my browser to know where to redirect. I'm not using any proxy for my browser or mac. My linode runs on ubuntu. Btw, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Oh, weird. I just did it twice in succession and got a 200, then a 301. tinyurl seems to be doing something awful =(

Comment: @minitech yes, I've found the same thing, first response 200 and if i try again within very short time, it responds 301. Is it part of any standard redirection technique? I'm confused!

Comment: No, it’s not standard. It’s for tracking and is really quite evil.

Comment: Then how does the browser know to ask for the page again? I was thinking if there are any standards like blank 200 response means ask me again?

Comment: It does include a `<meta http-equiv="Refresh">`; you just didn’t see it the second time, because it used a 301 that time. `curl -v` should help clear things up, if you can try it fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tinyurl appears to serve a 200 with a `<meta http-equiv="Refresh">` initially, then 301s for subsequent requests for some amount of time afterwards, so that it can set cookies (two of them!), run a ton of tracking scripts, and just generally slow people down.

That is to say, tinyurl sucks, and so do all URL shorteners. Good question.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but thought I'd update the answer since I ran into this today and came here first.

The -L flag follows redirects. This works on Centos 6, Centos 7, and OSX 10:

```
curl -L http://mytinyurl.com/67lwfe -o marketing.html
```

Sorry, SO doesn't like tinyurl's apparently.